# What is the highest Google Cloud Vision score a image:annotation can return?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am using Google Cloud Vision for a project and I'm planning on filtering results based on how reliable the score for the LOGO_DETECTION was.

I was running some tests found the result a LOGO_DETECTION on a image showing only Google´s plain logo (image below) returned a score of only **0.28542563**.

[image]

Scores range from 0-1 so I found this quite strange. I was wondering if the highest score is actually 0, and 1 the lowest. But I couldn´t find any reference to any of this on the documentation.

Does anyone here know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its plain, normalized to 1, *probability*, and when multiplied by 100 it gives the *percentage probability*.

So the highest is 1 and lowest is 0. But most probably, you'll get the numbers between 0 and 1 as scores.